# The 'word' variable loops and counts the same same string 9x before updating

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program that takes the sender's email address from an email list (saved to a .txt file), adds it to a dictionary, and counts how many times that email address is used to send emails on that list.

The program is supposed to take the address, store it in a variable (word), and check to see if it is being used as a dictionary key. If it is not, then it adds the address to the dictionary, with a val of 1. If it is, then it increments the address's value by 1. After that, the program moves on to the next address and updates the 'word' variable

The problem is that when the program checks to see if the address is in the dictionary, it increments the address's value, and repeats it again 8 more times. So every time an address is checked, it basically increments the address's value 9 times, before moving on to the next one.

I have fiddled with the code some, but there is not a lot of code, so there is not a lot I can do. I am dealing with nested for loops, if that helps. The only thing that seems to modify the answer is how I deal with identifying the lines the program is supposed to pay attention to. (See below)

The problem is somewhere in here:

```py
#Iterate through each line of the file
for line in fhand:
#Focus only on the sender lines
    if not line.startswith('From'): continue
#Turn every line into a list of strings
    words = line.split()

#Iterate through the words in the strings for the sender's address
    for word in words:
        #if words[0] != 'From':continue
        word = words[1]
        print(word)

#Add address of the dictionary/ increment address's value
        domain[word] = domain.get(word, 0) +1
```

The code goes from iterating each address nine times to iterating it seven times if I delete

```
if not line.startswith('From'): continue
```

And use

```py
if words[0] != 'From':continue
```

Tried getting rid of the nested loop:

```py
for line in fhand:
#Focus only on the sender lines
    #if not line.startswith('From'): continue
#Turn every line into a list of strings
    words = line.split()

#test
    if words[0] != 'From':continue
    word = words[1]
    #print(word)
    domain[word] = domain.get(word, 0) +1
```

Now the dictionary values are only twice as much as they should be.

Actual output:

```
{'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za': 4, 'louis@media.berkeley.edu': 6, 
'zqian@umich.edu': 8, 'rjlowe@iupui.edu': 4, 'cwen@iupui.edu': 10, 
'gsilver@umich.edu': 6, 'wagnermr@iupui.edu': 2, 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk': 
2, 'gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com': 2, 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za': 8, 
'ray@media.berkeley.edu': 2}
```

Expected output:

```
{'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za': 2, 'louis@media.berkeley.edu': 3,
 'zqian@umich.edu': 4, 'rjlowe@iupui.edu': 2, 'cwen@iupui.edu': 5, 
'gsilver@umich.edu': 3, 'wagnermr@iupui.edu': 1, 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk':
 1, 'gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com': 1, 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za': 4, 
'ray@media.berkeley.edu': 1}
```

Input- I tried to just copy and past the input, but it's too big. It can be found here: [mbox-short.txt](https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt)

Changed

```py
if not line.startswith('From'): continue
```

to

```py
if not line.startswith('From:'): continue
```

Adding that colon, along with getting rid of the nested loop, seems to have fixed my code.

This is solved.

Comment: instead of using 'not' use "if line.startswith('From'): break"

Comment: please give us the desired output if you can along with the input you are passing if possible.

Comment: Added the desired output. Had to edit it by hand from the actual output, but it seems accurate. Also added a link to the input. It was too large to just copy and paste in the question. If I use `if line.startswith('From'): break` that will break out of the loop without actually adding anything to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
#Iterate through each line of the file
for line in fhand:
#Focus only on the sender lines
    if not line.startswith('From'): continue

#Turn every line into a list of strings
    words = line.split()    
#Iterate through the words in the strings for the sender's address
    for word in words:
        #if words[0] != 'From':continue    
#Add address of the dictionary/ increment address's value
        domain[word] = domain.get(word, 0) +1
```

Comment: This got rid of the extra address iterations, but every word from the string (string from the list?) is being added into the dictionary instead of just the addresses.